# Passing an environment variable to a shell script from Fastlane

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, fastlane

I'm running [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) (a continuous build tool for iOS) in order to execute a custom shell script for decrypting a file.

This is the command.

```
sh "./decrypt.sh ENV['ENCRYPTION_P12']"
```

I cannot figured out a way to pass the environment variable to that script. Obviously, if I hardcode the pwd into the script, it works correctly.

```
sh "./decrypt.sh mypwd"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: BTW -- what language is Fastlane configuration written in? If it's Ruby, for instance, tagging the question for Ruby will get you people who know Ruby in here, as opposed to folks who only know shell -- or folks who know Fastlane, for which you might be waiting a while.

Comment: By the looks of your question, you're trying to pass a command line parameter to your script, not an environment variable.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, that was my first assumption as well [see the longer form of my answer in its edit history], but given as the OP is using fastlane, I'm guessing that they actually already have an environment variable and are trying to determine how to make a parameter of it.

Comment: BTW, Lorenzo -- if this is truly an environment variable, it's **already** passed to your script; you have no reason to put it on the command line and then pull it off your command line, you can just refer to it directly as `"$ENCRYPTION_P12"`.

Comment: Added ruby tag. Can you explain me downvote?

Comment: I can't -- not mine.

Comment: BTW, I've expanded my answer to go into the security risks of doing this the wrong way (substituting variables into code passed to the shell as a script).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Expanding From Within The Immediate Shell

Assuming that `sh`, here, is a fastlane command that invokes a shell command with the given argument as script text:

```
# as a fastlane directive
sh './decrypt.sh "$ENCRYPTION_P12"'
```

Note that if this were being literally invoked as a command line for `/bin/sh`, it would need a `-c` argument:

```
# in other contexts
sh -c './decrypt.sh "$ENCRYPTION_P12"'
```

Note that this absolutely depends on `ENCRYPTION_P12` being an environment variable -- that is, `export`ed to the environment by the system by which it was set.

---

#### Expanding from Within The Invoked Script

That said, if it **is** an environment variable, you have a better option: Just use it.

That is, inside `decrypt.sh`, you can refer to `"$ENCRYPTION_P12"` without needing to set it explicitly, as the shell implicitly imports all environment variables as shell variables -- and they're passed down to child processes without any explicit actions needed.

---

#### Things to Avoid: Shell Injection Attacks

Finally, an aside: The dangerous way to do this would have been something like:

```
# INSECURE: DO NOT DO THIS
sh "./decrypt.sh #{ENV['ENCRYPTION_P12']}"
```

or

```
# STILL INSECURE
sh "./decrypt.sh \"#{ENV['ENCRYPTION_P12'}\""
```

or

```
# STILL INSECURE
sh "./decrypt.sh '#{ENV['ENCRYPTION_P12'}'"
```

...thereby substituting the value into your generated string at the Ruby level. This is dangerous, however, as that string is parsed as code -- meaning that contents of `ENCRYPTION_P12` could then be leveraged in shell attacks.

For instance, consider the case (given below in bash syntax):

```
# this will make any of the above do Very Evil Things
ENCRYPTION_P12=$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''
```

...for which both `rm`s will execute if directly substituted into generated shell script (as opposed to expanded during parameter expansion -- `'${foo}'` -- which takes place *after* the expansion phases which make this dangerous have already passed).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Is there any difference between the usage of $ and # symbols for variables? See first snippet and third one.

Comment: @LorenzoB., a huge difference: `#{foo}` is evaluated by Ruby before shell parsing starts, `${foo}` is evaluated by the shell after most syntax-parsing stages are already complete. This is why `#{foo}` introduces security risks: Content substituted in that way can be parsed by the shell as if it were code.

Comment: I am trying to execute a shell script going one directory back. I also need to pass a param to this script dynamically like this, `lane :addPrivateKey do | options |
 sh ('cd .. &&  ./add_key.sh options[:clientKey]')
end`. Right now its taking options[:clientKey] as the param instead of the actual param sent to the lane. I know it is in string that's why but how to get it out from options variable?

Comment: @nr5, if you trust the value not to be malicious, use `#{options[:clientKey]}`. If it has spaces or literal quotes you might need to add an appropriate type of quotes around it. If you can't guarantee that the value is safe, then you might want to write Ruby code that exports it as an environment variable so you can safely access it through that variable's name.

Comment: is it possible to do the reverse i.e. send a value from the fastlane env to the outer script? I specifically want to make the provisioning profile ID available for subsequent commands after `fastlane match` is complete.

Answer (score 4):

The fastlane specific answer is https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#shell-values

or, from within your Fastfile:
    `decrypted = sh("./decrypt" ENV[ENCRYPTION_P12])`